# Parse json to java object: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, spring, gson

Can someone help me with parsing json string to object, I´m trying but always get error like this:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

Here is my code:

Item class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Item{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;
    
    @JsonProperty("dTime")
    long dTime;
    
    @JsonProperty("aTime")
    long aTime;
}
```

converting json to object:

```
String jsonString = "[
    [
        {
            "id":"string",
            "dTime": 1111111111,
            "aTime": 1111111111
        },
        {
            "id":"string",
            "dTime": 1111111111,
            "aTime": 1111111111
        }
    ]
]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
List<Item> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);

System.out.println(gson.toJson(list));
```

**Update:**
Because i get this json as response from external API:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

Is it possible to make this converting to Array of Item objects inside this restTemplate.exchange(..) or this with gson is better way?

Comment: The input JSON string contains duplicate list/array. You could either fix the type of the parsed object to be `List<List<Item>>` or strip the extra pair of `[` and `]`: `jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length() - 1)`

Comment: Yes, you have two objects within an array within an array. According to the JSON you have, it should be `List<List<Item>>`.

Comment: [The answer by Eklavya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64533992/13279831) provides better handling of the response - it transforms the string returned by the external API into `List<List<Item>>`  immediately, without extra manual parsing with `Gson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ParameterizedTypeReference` to directly map in java list object  and use `List<List<Item>>` since your data wrap in `[]`

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<List<Item>>> responseType =
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<List<Item>>>() {};
ResponseEntity<List<List<Item>>> response = 
                    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, responseType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsonString has an extra '['. It should be

```
String jsonString = "
[
    {
        "id":"string",
        "dTime": 1111111111,
        "aTime": 1111111111
    },
    {
        "id":"string",
        "dTime": 1111111111,
        "aTime": 1111111111
    }
]
";
```